# how to change back ground colour in grid view if column date is more then todays date

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i want to show if renewal date column date greater than todays date then it should highlight with background color = red . here im not getting the value in cell 7. the value is in renewal date col -  15-02-2014

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Renewal Date"  >
        <ItemTemplate>
              <a href='ChangeRenewaldate.aspx?Linkid=<%#Eval ("LinkId")%>'>
              <asp:Label ID="lblRenewal" runat="server"  Text='<%# Eval("RenewalDate","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>          </ItemTemplate>    
     </asp:TemplateField>


protected void GrdV_Projects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells[7].Text))
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[7].Text > DateTime.Now.ToString())
                {

                    e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {

                    e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `TemplateFields` you have to use `FindControl` to get a reference to a control, if you use `BoundFields` you have to use `e.Row.Cell[index].Text`. So you could use following:

```
Label lblRenewal = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblRenewal");
```

to find the `Label` and then parse it's `Text`.

But in this case you should prefer using the `DataSource` of the `GridViewRow` to get the real `DateTime` instead of parsing strings:

```
protected void GrdV_Projects_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        DateTime renewalDate = row.Field<DateTime>("RenewalDate");
        if (renewalDate.Date > DateTime.Today)
            e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        else
            e.Row.Cells[7].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
}
```